# Using jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.6.1 but noConflict doesn't work

Tags: facebook, fixed, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 for a fixed bar on my site that scrolls with the site as you scroll.

But I'm also using 1.6.1 for a facebook thing I'm doing, and when I add them together, the bar breaks and the facebook thing works, but when I add the noConflict in, the bar works, but the facebook breaks, so if you could look at my code, and help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link type="text/css" href="themes/default/jx.stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mc$ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.jixedbar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
mc$(document).ready(function() {
    mc$("#floating-bar").jixedbar();
}); 
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
margin: auto;
background-image: url(template.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="floating-bar">
  <ul>
        <li title="Home"><a href="http://www.atomicstarstudios.com/"><img src="icons/home.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="jx-separator-left"></span>
    <ul>        
        <li title="Around The Web"><a href="#"><img src="icons/network.png" alt="Share" /></a>
            <ul>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<!-- USE 'Asynchronous Loading' version, for IE8 to work
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/ -->

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : '209445949091775',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>




                <li><a id="share_button" href="#"><img src="icons/facebook.png" title="Facebook" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Facebook</a></li>
              <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#share_button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: 'Atomic Star Studios',
link: 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/Atomic-Star-Studios/228192187207829',
picture: 'http://www.atomicstarstudios.com/logo.jpg',
caption: 'http://www.atomicstarstudios.com/',
description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
message: 'Visit Atomic Star Studios for excellent prices on great printg and professional design! We Have All Your Marketing Needs!!!'
});
});
});
</script>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/atomstars"><img src="icons/twitter.png" title="Twitter" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Twitter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="jx-separator-left"></span>
    <ul>
        <li title"Top Pages"><a href="#">Top Pages</a>
            <ul>
                <li title="About"><a href="#"><img src="icons/info.png" alt="About" /></a></li>
                <li title="Products"><a href="#"><img src="icons/blogs.png" alt="Products" /></a></li>
                <li title="Portfolio"><a href="#"><img src="icons/block.png" alt="Portfolio" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="jx-separator-left"></span>        
    <div class="text-container">Like us on Facebook!</div>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/pages/Atomic-Star-Studios/228192187207829&layout=button_count&send=true&show_faces=false&width=100&action=like" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:30px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/atomstars" class="twitter-follow-button">Follow @atomstars</a>
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <span class="jx-separator-left"></span>
    <ul>
        <li title="Facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Atomic-Star-Studios/228192187207829"><img src="icons/facebook.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li title="Twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/atomstars"><img src="icons/twitter.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="jx-separator-left"></span>
    <ul>
        <li title="Chat with us Live!"><a href="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.atomicstarstudios.com/livezilla/chat.php','','width=590,height=610,left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,menubar=no,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes'))"><img src="http://www.atomicstarstudios.com/livezilla/image.php?id=04&amp;type=inlay"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="jx-separator-right"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you fix the script instead of including an ancient jQuery version?

Comment: Is telling the jQuery developers to preserve backwards-compatibility in a less half-assed way than `noConflict` (which does nothing apart from unbinding the alias on `$`) an option?  There's no reason why jQuery 1.6.1 can't provide 1.4.2 style behavior to code that expects it apart from that the developers decided not to bother.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code.

First, you should call the `noConflict` in-between both jQuery requests, not after the second one. You need to load the modules you need with each version of jQuery with the version so that when you call noConflict, references to the plugins are moved with it. You should also add "true" to noConflict so that all references to jQuery are removed before loading the second one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.jixedbar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mc$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For more information, see the [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) documentation.

**With that said, you should really consider find a way to not have to do this. It is not an elegant way to use jQuery.**

**TO ANSWER @TGR**: Try this for yourself and you'll see for yourself that my solution works perfectly fine:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jixedbar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/jquery.jixedbar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var mc$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function()
      {
        alert('jQuery ' + mc$.fn.jquery + ': ' + ( typeof mc$.fn.jixedbar ));
        alert('jQuery ' + jQuery.fn.jquery + ': ' + ( typeof jQuery.fn.fixedbar ));
      });
    </script>

    <title>6367968</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>6367968</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The first alert will show "jQuery 1.4.2: function" while the second one will show "jQuery 1.6.1: undefined".

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I've tested the code above and it's working fine. I know you said it's doing something with Facebook. Is that what's not working?

Comment: Yes thats not whats working, the bar itself works ut when I click the button for it to do the thing it's supposed to do (which is open a content box to post on your fb wall)

Comment: If found the problem with your code: change `$('#share_button').click(function(e){` to `$('#share_button').live('click', function(e){` and that should solve it.

Comment: @Jacob - Change it to `$('#share_button').die('click').live('click', function(e){` (I added a `.die('click')` in the front of `.live`).

Comment: Awesome thank you tons that worked perfect now one more question for you though... We want to put it in a lightbox popup instead of a new window how would we go about that at this point?

Comment: @Jacob - I'm not sure as I've never implemented that before. It looks like it's a `FB.init()` is managing that so you might not be able to. You should check the Facebook documentation or post another question. With that said, both of jQuery's `.live()` and `.die()` were available in jQuery 1.4.1 (hence in 1.4.2). You might be able to do away with jQuery 1.6.1 and that whole noConflict thing too. Either way, I've had a long night (I live in Vancouver, Canada) so I'm off to bed.

Comment: Thanks again Francois was a problem area that was racking our brains very hard and you made it work! Kudos my friend!

Answer (score 1):

1. load jQuery 1.4
2. load all plugins which need to use 1.4
3. use `noConflict`
4. load jQuery 1.6

The problem is that jQuery plugins tend to be written this way:

```
(function($) {
    // plugin code using $ for jQuery calls
})(jQuery)
```

i. e. they have an internal copy of whatever `window.jQuery` was at the time the plugin loaded, and you cannot change that afterwards.

**update:** a little more detail on how `noConflict` works (was too long for the comments). When you load jQuery, it creates an object containing all its functions and data, and sets `window.$` and `window.jQuery` to that object. The old value of `window.$` and `window.jQuery` is saved in the object.

When you call `noConflict`, it restores the saved value (by default for `$`; if you call it with `true`, also for `jQuery`). This is useful if you had something in those variables *before* loading jQuery, and don't want it to be overwritten. E.g. if you loaded things like this:

1. load jQuery 1.6
2. load jQuery 1.4
3. call `noConflict(true)`

then the first step would put jQuery 1.6 into `$` and `jQuery`, the second would overwrite them with 1.4, and  `noConflict` would restore `$` and `jQuery` to the 1.6 version.

But since you load  1.4 first, and call `noConflict` between the two, the old value for `$` and `jQuery` which is restored is `undefined`, which is not particularly useful, and will be overwritten by 1.6 anyway, so the `noConflict` call does not do anything useful beyond returning the value of `$` which then can be stored by some other name (`$mc` in this case). `var $mc = $;` would work just as well for that.

As for the plugins, the auto-executing function copies the value of `window.jQuery` at the moment the plugin is loaded, and it does not matter at all what happens to `window.jQuery` afterwards:

```
window.jQuery = 'foo';

(function($) {
    window.fun = function () {
        console.log($);
    }
})(jQuery);

window.jQuery = 'bar';

fun(); // will log 'foo'
```

Comment: @Tgr - Your answer is identical to mine but (which is great) but could be a little confusing when you add "they have an interal copy of whatever window.jQuery...". I just wanted to clarify that the reason why you call `jQuery.noConflict(true)` after loading all of the modules is to fix that exact problem.

Comment: @Francois Deschenes: that is not quite true. When you load jQuery, it creates an object storing all its functions and data, and sets `window.jQuery` and `window.$` to it. When the scripts are loaded in the order you recommend, jQuery 1.6 overwrites all references to 1.4 (except in plugins, which keep their own copy); the only real function of the `noConflict` call is to save the 1.4 module to a variable. You could just as well write `var $mc = $` instead. Calling `noConflict` with or without `true` makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @Tgr - Adding "true" to `noConflict` changes the namespace of jQuery from window.jQuery to a variable of your choice. From that moment onward, window.jQuery, jQuery or $ would no longer be defined.

Comment: @Tgr - Your code isn't proving anything. Have a look at my example above. I've provided a full example that proves that my answer works and that noConflict does moves plugins along with jQuery when you call `noConflict(true)`. Create the HTML file on your desktop and see for yourself.

Comment: @Francois Deschenes: of course it is working, you just don't seem to understand *why* it is working. Replace `var mc$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);` with `var mc$ = $;` and it will still work. (Also, you mistyped `jixedbar`, though it does not change the results.)

Comment: @Tgr - Gotcha... Of course you're right. Sorry, I'm a little tired tonight. I live in Vancouver (right next to Rogers Arena) and it was insane here today. [Vancouver Riot 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver_riot_2011).